# Changing y axis on multiple subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I am fairly new to python and matplotlib. I have the following problem:

I want to plot six climatic drivers over 2000 years. Since each plot represents a different driver, I want to give each y-axis a different label, but am not able to index each subplot. Please see the following code and  subsequent error message:

```
###Plot MET drivers
fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 14))

for ii, name_MET in enumerate (["Day_since_start_of_sim", "Min._Temp", "Max._Temp", "Radiation","CO2_(ppm)","DOY"]):
        ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(2,3,ii+1)
        ax3.plot(drivers,'g-',label='2001')
        ax3.set_title(name_MET)
        ax3.set_xlabel('years')
        ax3[1].set_ylabel('Day_since_start_of_simulation')
        ax3[2].set_ylabel('Degrees C')
        ax3[3].set_ylabel('Degrees C')
        ax3[4].set_ylabel('MJ m-2 d-1')
        ax3[5].set_ylabel('ppm')
        ax3[6].set_ylabel('Days')
        ax3.set_xticks(incr_plot_years)
        ax3.set_xticklabels((incr_plot_years/365).astype('S'), rotation = 45)
        ax3.set_xlim(0,ax3.get_xlim()[1])
        ax3.set_ylim(0,ax3.get_ylim()[1])
```

Error message:

```
    287     ax3.set_title(name_MET)
    288     ax3.set_xlabel('years')
--> 289     ax3[1].set_ylabel('Day_since_start_of_simulation')
    290     ax3[2].set_ylabel('Degrees C')
    291     ax3[3].set_ylabel('Degrees C')

TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

Can anyone help please how I get to name each y-axis individually? It would help me a lot!

Thank you,

Comment: Has your question been sufficiently addressed? If so, you can help other users by marking the correct answer with the checkbox. Otherwise, what is missing from these answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you enumerate the list of names you want to have on the axes, so you can use the current name in each iteration like so:

```
fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 14))

names =["Day_since_start_of_sim", "Min._Temp", "Max._Temp", 
        "Radiation","CO2_(ppm)","DAY"]

for ii, name_MET in enumerate (names):
    ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(2,3,ii+1)
    ax3.plot(drivers[ii],'g-',label='2001')# - unclear what drivers is?
    ax3.set_title(name_MET)
    ax3.set_xlabel('years')
    ax3.set_ylabel(name_MET)
    ax3.set_xticks(incr_plot_years) # - unclear
    ax3.set_xticklabels((incr_plot_years/365).astype('S'), rotation = 45)
    ax3.set_xlim(0,ax3.get_xlim()[1])
    ax3.set_ylim(0,ax3.get_ylim()[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to index into `ax3`, but `ax3` represents one subplot, not the entire plot. Instead, you should label each y-axis on its corresponding loop iteration. Try this:

```
names_MET = ["Day_since_start_of_sim", "Min._Temp", "Max._Temp", "Radiation","CO2_(ppm)","DOY"]
ylabels = ['Day_since_start_of_simulation', 'Degrees C', 'Degrees C', 'MJ m-2 d-1', 'ppm', 'Days']

for ii, (name_MET, ylabel) in enumerate(zip(names_MET, ylabels)):
    ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(2,3,ii+1)
    ax3.plot(drivers,'g-',label='2001')
    ax3.set_title(name_MET)
    ax3.set_xlabel('years')
    ax3.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax3.set_xticks(incr_plot_years)
    ax3.set_xticklabels((incr_plot_years/365).astype('S'), rotation = 45)
    ax3.set_xlim(0,ax3.get_xlim()[1])
    ax3.set_ylim(0,ax3.get_ylim()[1])
```

The important benefit here is that you get to provide custom labels for the y-axis, instead of having to use the values you defined in `names_MET`. For instance, the units `'Degrees C'` instead of simply `'Min._Temp'`.